# how to delete partition and install windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have windows XP on my pc , now i want to remove all partitions from my pc and install Windows 7.

I have a bootable windows 7 cd , I have set the boot sequence to Cd drive, now when i start my pc , it takes me directly to windows 7 Installation, But before that i want to Delete all partitions from my pc and then install Windows 7 , whats the best way to do that .

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply boot from the Windows 7 DVD and start the setup. In the setup you get a step where you must choose where you want to install Windows 7. Here you can delete all old partitions and create new one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Part of the install process is to change your partitions and do a format. If you want something more destructive, then download DBAN or another disk zeroing software (DBAN is / was free) Western Digital and all HD manufacturers have a zero utility if you want to go that route.